# Get a clean read out of distinct actions in the column, splitting on multiple delimiters in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working a SQL table in Snowflake and would like to extract characters seen before the delimiters 'to','from', and '-'. I would like to select the distinct results from this to return something like:

```
| entry                      |
| -------------------------  |
| Checked Out Client return  |
| Checked In Client return   |
| Backed up Client return    |
| Copied Client return       |
| Restored Client return     |
| Imported prior year return |
| Permanently deleting file  |
```

Right now the table reads:

```
| entry                                               |
| --------------------------------------------------  |
|Imported prior year return - \\Office-hub\programs\TaxACT\TaxACT 2019 Professional Edition\Client Data\JOHN SMITH's 2019 Individual Tax Return (2) (2).ta9 to Untitled |
|Imported prior year return - \\Office-hub\programs\TaxACT\TaxACT 2019 Professional Edition\Client Data |
|Removing file - C:\TaxACT\TaxAct 2020 Professional Edition\Client Data\Oliver's 2020 Individual Tax Return.ta0|
|Permanently deleting file - C:\TaxACT\TaxAct 2020 Professional Edition\Client Data\ |
|Checked Out Client Return - test's Tax Return (1040) |
|Checked In Client Return - Lee's Tax Return (1040)|
|Restored client return from d:\\|
|Performing Undo Checkout on client - E:\CLIENTS\TAXES\2020\STONE INC's 2021|
```

I've tried

```
select distinct(result) from
(select
    case
        when "entry" LIKE '% - %' 
        then STRTOK("entry", 'from', 0)       
        when "entry" LIKE '% from %' 
        then STRTOK("entry", 'from', 1)
        when "entry" LIKE '% to %' 
        then STRTOK("entry", 'to', 1)
        else 'other'
    end as result
 from "TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD"."PREPONLINE2020"."ACTIVITYLOG"
```

And also have tried replacing STRTOK with SPLIT_PART? The data type of the column is TEXT but some of the TEXT is a link? Not sure if that's affecting my results. How would I get a clean read out of individual actions seen in Snowflake SQL? Note that any PID has been changed.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

STRTOK doesn't work in your case because, according to the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok.html), the delimiter is "Text representing the set of delimiters to tokenize on. Each character in the delimiter string is a delimiter."

You can use SPLIT_PART like this

```
select distinct(result) from (
select
    case
        when entry LIKE '% - %' 
            then split_part(entry, '-', 1)       
        when entry LIKE '% from %' 
            then split_part(entry, 'from', 1)
        when entry LIKE '% to %' 
            then split_part(entry, 'to', 1)
        else 'other'
    end as result
 from "TAXACT_EDW_RAW_PRD"."PREPONLINE2020"."ACTIVITYLOG"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

OR another option is to chain logic together,

unfortunately POSITION return zero on failure, and LEAST treats null as the lowest value, so a NULLIFZERO will not work, so we have to write our own LEAST:

```
select 
    position('from', column1) as from_pos
    ,position('to', column1) as to_pos
    ,position('-', column1) as hyphen_pos
    ,iff(from_pos = 0, 100000, from_pos) as fpos
    ,iff(to_pos = 0, 100000, to_pos) as tpos
    ,iff(hyphen_pos = 0, 100000, hyphen_pos) as hpos
    ,least(fpos, tpos, hpos) as l
    ,substr(column1, 1, iff(l = 100000, length(column1), l-1)) as result
from values 
    ('Imported prior year return - \\\\Office-hub\\programs\\TaxACT\\TaxACT 2019 Professional Edition\\Client Data\\JOHN SMITH\'s 2019 Individual Tax Return (2) (2).ta9 to Untitled '),
    ('Imported prior year return - \\Office-hub\programs\\TaxACT\\TaxACT 2019 Professional Edition\\Client Data'),
    ('Removing file - C:\TaxACT\\TaxAct 2020 Professional Edition\\Client Data\\Oliver\'s 2020 Individual Tax Return.ta0'),
    ('Restored client return from d:\\'),
    ('This matches none of these rules')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html)

```
select 
    REGEXP_Substr(column1, '([^-]+)\s*((from)|(to)|(-))',1,1,'ie',1)
from values 
    ('Imported prior year return - \\\\Office-hub\\programs\\TaxACT\\TaxACT 2019 Professional Edition\\Client Data\\JOHN SMITH\'s 2019 Individual Tax Return (2) (2).ta9 to Untitled '),
    ('Imported prior year return - \\Office-hub\programs\\TaxACT\\TaxACT 2019 Professional Edition\\Client Data'),
    ('Removing file - C:\TaxACT\\TaxAct 2020 Professional Edition\\Client Data\\Oliver\'s 2020 Individual Tax Return.ta0'),
    ('Restored client return from d:\\')
```

gives:

| REGEXP_SUBSTR |
| --- |
| Imported prior year return |
| Imported prior year return |
| Removing file |
| Restored client return |